# Printing data horizontally with one main heading (C# Winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms

As it stands, I am writing some data to a txt file from textboxes in a form. My question here is that How do I make my data get printed horizontally rather than vertically. Normally the data gets written like:

Manufacturer: Ferrari

Model: 458

Fault: Oil

But I want the data to be written like this:

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions or even if this is possible? I need it to only have one title rather than constantly printing the title with it as well.

here is the code that writes it to a txt file:

```
string line = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, new string[]
            {
                $"Manufacturer: {lstManu}",
                $"Model: {lstModel}",
                $"Fault: {faultNature}",
                $"Last Service: {lastService}",
                $"Estimated Cost: £{estimatedCost}",
                $"Client Name: {fisrtName}",
                $"Client Surname: {secondName}",
                $"Unique Refrence Number: {uniqueRefrenceNumber}",
                $"Contact Number: {contactDetails}",
                $"Part Name: {partName}",
                $"Part Number: {partNumber}",
                $"Part Manufacturer: {partManufacturer}",
                $"Part Price: £{partPrice}",
                $"Mechanic Name: {mechanicName}",
                $"Job Refrence Number: {jobRefrenceNumber}",
                $"Time Taken: {timeTaken}",
                $"Problem Solved? : {problemSolved}",
                $"Summary Refrence Number: {summaryRefrenceNumber}",
                $"Total Cost: £{totalCost}",
                "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------",
            });



        File.AppendAllLines("Repair Database June.txt", new string[] { line });
```

Comment: Thought of using datagridview or listview?

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya I am actually working on it now. I have found a different solution, but once I finish it I will upload the code.